# Problem with how to calculate sum of integers from file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, sum, integer

I have file in this format:

```
4651
9537
8154
```

I have to calculate a sum of each row. I try something like this:

```
 string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(@"myPath"); // put each row of file in the array
 for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
       string[] subFiles = files[i].Split(','); // try to make array of each files array element
       float sum = 0;
       for(int k = 0; k < subFiles.Length; k++) {
             float number = Singe.Parse(subFiles[k]); // convert each element of subFiles into float
             sum += number;
       }
       Console.WriteLine(sum);   
}
```

When I log this, a got the exact format that I have in file:

```
4651
9537
8154
```

If someone can tell me where is the mistake, and how can I do it, i will appreciate it.

Comment: You seem to expect a comma-separated list of integers in each line, but there is only one per line.

Comment: The sum of `4651` is `4651`. I'm not sure what exactly you expect. Are you trying to calculate the sum per row/line or per file? On another note, `files` and `subFiles` are poorly chosen names when they refer to the lines (or parts of a line) and not the files.

Comment: You should be getting a compile error on `Singe.Parse`, if nothing else...

Comment: @HereticMonkey why should he get an error,  `Single` it's still a floating-point number.

Comment: @styx `Single.Parse` would work fine. `Singe.Parse` sounds like something you'd do over a stove...

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `float sum = 0;` inside the loop which resetting the result every loop,you need to move it outside like this

```
 float sum = 0;
 string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(@"1.txt"); // put each row of file in the array
 for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
 {
     ///reset of your code
 }
```

output

> 4651 14188 22342

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the fact that each line is a `string`, and is therefore an `IEnumerable<char>`, which can be queried using LINQ:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"myPath"))
{
    double sum = line.Sum(Char.GetNumericValue);
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

`Char.GetNumericValue` gets the `double` representation of each character, which can be summed.